# Unable to load third party scripts on Safari

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, cross-domain

I am trying to load Dropbox choose SDK on my website. But running in to an issue on Mac Safari browser.

```
<script async="" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="crbrplpove29sb2"></script>
```

but script doesnt load on xconvert.com (if you goto the network tab and load https://www.xconvert.com/compress-mp4, it won't show dropins.js). I also tried manually injecting the script to the header once the page is loaded

```
const node = document.createElement('script');
node.src = 'https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js';
node.type = 'text/javascript';
node.setAttribute('id', 'dropboxjs');
node.setAttribute('data-app-key', 'crbrplpove29sb2');
node.defer = true;
                          
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].append(node);
```

But same code on other websites such as smallpdf and ilovepdf seem to work perfectly.

There is a preference on Safari, under Privacy saying 'Prevent cross-site tracking'. If I turn it off, then the script loads perfect on the xconvert. But that setting don't need to be turned off for other websites I meantioned above.

Any idea what may be causing this issue?

It almost feels like Apple whitelist some website and block others from loading third-party scripts. Same thing happens if I try to load Google APIs as well. This only happens on Safari. It works fine on Chrome.

Safari version: 14.1.2
Mac version: 11.6

Following is the error thrown on script which is not much helpful
https://discussions.apple.com/content/attachment/04520a01-1b75-45e2-9fc4-039e7c1c9a9b

Comment: Hi, could you show a screenshot of your console, in the "error" tab? Thanks

Comment: this is the error https://discussions.apple.com/content/attachment/04520a01-1b75-45e2-9fc4-039e7c1c9a9b. It doesn't have much info.